# If I inherit some attributes from father's pure virtual class and want to implement them in main, do I have to redefine them in the inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, attributes, virtual-inheritance

If I inherit some attributes from my father's pure virtual class and want to implement them in main, do I have to redefine them in the inherited class?
This is pure virtual class Father with attributes m_name and m_preperties.
There is inherited class Son. Son has his own attribute m_school and also Father's **m_name and m_properties**.
I would like to implement all three values in main. 
I know how to implement son's attribute school, but do I implement Father's attributes right? I ask because I define it same like non-inherited attributes and it looks strange for me.
Thank you
UPDATE: I made Father's attributes defined in Son.h as comment. But not i still don't work. This is error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\mirek\CLionProjects\family\cmake-build-debug --target family -j 6
[1/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/family.dir/main.cpp.obj
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/family.dir/Son.cpp.obj
[3/3] Linking CXX executable family.exe
FAILED: family.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -g  CMakeFiles/family.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/family.dir/Father.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/family.dir/Son.cpp.obj -o family.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libfamily.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/family.dir/Son.cpp.obj:Son.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV3Son[.refptr._ZTV3Son]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for Son'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Father.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Father.h"

class Father {
protected:
    std::string m_name;
    std::vector<std::string> m_properties;

public:
    virtual int calculateSalary() = 0;
};
```

Father.cpp

```
#include "Father.h"
```

Son.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Father.h"

class Son: public Father{

    std::string m_school;

    //std::string m_name;  //is it right?
    //std::vector<std::string> m_properties; //is it right?


public:
    Son(std::string school, std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties);
    int calculateSalary();
};
```

Son.cpp

```
#include "Son.h"

Son::Son(std::string school, std::string name, std::vector<std::string> properties){
    m_school = school;
    m_name = name;
    m_properties = properties;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Son* son1 = new Son("Harward", "Mirek", {"asd","yxc"}); //Son's school attribute and Father's attribute name and properties vector
}
```

Comment: The thing about *inheritance* is that derived classes *inherit* their parent's properties. So, no, you don 't have to add the declarations of `m_name` and `m_properties` in `Son`, as they will be inherited from `Father`.

Comment: And you most certainly **don't** want `#include "Father.h"` in Father.h.

Comment: @AdrianMole But when I make comment from two Fathers attributes defined in Son.h, it stop works. This is main question, which I asked for. So what is right solution in this example?

Comment: In your code, you have what is known as [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15734562/10871073). The two 'new' members of `Son` will (effectively) hide those of the same name in any `Father` object, so changes made to the Son members will *not* affect the `Father` members. Further, you are redefining those as `private` members.

Comment: If what you have works but, without the shadow members your code doesn't work as you want, then you'll need to give us more details - a [MRE].

Comment: After I commened it, this is error: https://justpaste.it/4e8xg

Comment: (1) Don't show errors as images. (2) That looks like you commented other stuff out, as well - not just the two inherited data members.

Comment: No, I commented just two inherited attributes in Son.h: 
    std::string m_name;  //is it right?
    std::vector<std::string> m_properties; //is it right?

Comment: `m_name` and `m_properties` are `private` in `Father` so not accessible from `Son` (but are in `Son`). Make them `protected` or preferably add means to access them.

Comment: @dalfaB No, they are `protected` in `Father` but `private` in `Son`.

Comment: So I need to make protected in Son?

Comment: You need to show us code that we can compile to try to generate the error message you cite. You also need to add that error **as text** in the question. Now, I'm voting to close this question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065154/undefined-reference-to-vtable) -- Where is the definition of `Son::calculateSalary()`?

Comment: *"I would like to implement all three values in main."* -- "Implement" is not the right word. Based on your code, it looks like you mean either "initialize" or "specify values for".

Comment: I added int Son::calculateSalary() {
    return 0; 
} to Son.cpp and it works now

Comment: _//is it right?_ No